# Tiniest kernel for ubuntu

Tags: drivers, kernel, lts

Does exist a very minimal kernel for Ubuntu? I mean a kernel that does not support floppy drives, COM Port, and not common or so no longer used modules?

I wonder if removing support for these useless deprecated devices would improve the performances of an old laptop (a bit younger than Windows Vista).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in general it would not improve performance. First of all, the modules are generally not loaded if there's no hardware for them. For instance, the floppy modules will not be loaded, unless you have a floppy drive.

You can verify which modules the system has loaded with

```
lsmod | less
```

Press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit less.

A modern system will typically have tens of modules supporting various subsystems.

If you attempt to load a module that has no corresponding device, it will very often not load:

```
$ sudo modprobe floppy
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'floppy': No such device
```

But even if it were to load, it would not take up any significant amount of CPU time - as it would never be called by anything. The only resource overhead would be a tiny amount of RAM. In addition, your computer probably spends most of its resources on user space applications, not device drivers, so optimizing the kernel will probably give slim performance benefits, compared to switching to a lighter desktop environment.

Comment: So the only gain would be about space disk occupied by the ".ko" files ?

Comment: Yes, in general that would be the difference

Answer (score 2):

Not as such. But, since Linux is open source you may download the kernel source and configure it any way you like, build it, and boot.

Comment: I expected this answer ;)  I have failed so many times, used so many tutos outdated... This is why for now I do not want to try anymore and ask this. However I thank you for your answer. Have a nice day.